# Should I write components in Delphi instead of C++ Builder? How do I add events to a component?

Tags: c++, delphi, events, components, c++builder

I use C++ Builder (XE2) and I would need to develop some VCL components that would also be used in Delphi. As I understand C++ Builder supports Delphi code and Delphi components but not the other way around? If so, it would be better to start writing it in Delphi so that I don't do a double job?

Second part of my question is more technical; I know how to add a property in a VCL component but don't know how to add events. Could someone give me an example please (no matter Delphi or C++ Builder).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please realize that there is no limit on the number of questions you're allowed to post, so you should not feel pressured to include all your questions in a single post. Your question about language preference has nothing to do with your question about event properties, so you should really post them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As I understand C++ Builder supports Delphi code and Delphi components but not the other way around?*

*On source level - yes.
But if you choose to distribute your library sourceless - BPL+DCP+DCU - then it would not matter, except for maybe some small incompatibilities, like Delphi lacking [] operator and C++ lacking virtual overloaded constructors.*

***Turns out this estimation was wrong. Read Remy's comment below***

---

Most close to you example ov events is the VCL itself, sources are usually shipped with Delphi. If you have Delphi Starter/Trial without VCL sources - then get any opensource VCL library or component. Such as JediVCL or basically almost ANY VCL component with sources. For example any ["FWS" (Free with sources)](http://torry.net/pages.php?id=20) component 99% uses events.

Most basic and widely used event notifications type - such as TButton.OnClick, TForm.OnCreate and a lot of - is TNotifyEvent

Open [Delphi Help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent) for that type. Scroll to "See also" and see two links there.

- [Procedural types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types) are like **int (*f)(void)** in C.
- [Events creating manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_Events_-_Overview)

Comment: C++Builder cannot create DCP/DCU files for Delphi to use. It can only produce BPI/BPL files. It is not possible to create Packages in C++ that can be used statically in Delphi, but it can create Packages that can be used dynamically. If you want to support both Delphi and C++Builder, write the component in Delphi only and turn on its option to generate C++ output files.

Comment: Thanks Remy. That is my plan.

Answer (score 2):

Such as:
(borrowed code from about.delphi.com)

```
type
  TState = (stStarted, stStopped);
  TStateChangeEvent = procedure
  (Sender : TObject; State : TState) of object;

  TThirdComponent = class(TSecondComponent) // or whatever
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FState  : TState;
    FOnStart,
    FOnStop  : TNotifyEvent;
    FOnStateChange  : TStateChangeEvent;
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Start; override;
    procedure Stop; override;
    property State : TState
      read FState;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property OnStart : TNotifyEvent
      read FOnStart
      write FOnStart;
    property OnStateChange : TStateChangeEvent
      read FOnStateChange
      write FOnStateChange;
    property OnStop : TNotifyEvent
      read FOnStop
      write FOnStop;
  end
```

Then you can do

```
procedure TThirdComponent.Start;
begin
  inherited; 
  FState := stStarted;
  if Assigned(OnStart) then OnStart(Self);
  if Assigned(OnStateChange) then 
    OnStateChange(Self, State);
end;
```

Comment: Could you please explain this part:

property OnStart : TNotifyEvent
      read FOnStart
      write FOnStart;

Comment: What exactly is to explain there ? TNotifyEvent is pointer to a procedure https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&rls=ru&q=TNotifyEvent+docwiki&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

You either leave it nil or assigne address of your procedure to it.

int (*f)(void) if i remember some C

Comment: Funny thing, when you read about TNotifyEvent in official Delphi documentation (link above) there is See Also section. And 2nd link there is manual "How to create events)

Comment: To clarify it;
  * you create a new instance of ThirdComponent, define a procedure with the same parameters as defined in
  **TStateChangeEvent = procedure  (Sender : TObject; State : TState) of object;** or **TNotifyEvent** ;
 assign the new defined procedure to the according property.
 **newInstance.onStateChange := ThingsToDoOnStateChange;**
 when you call newInstance.Start then your procedure will get at the according place defined in ThirdComponent.Start method.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to implement soon.